# Number of iterations in nested loop (8051)

Tags: microcontroller, programming, 8051, code, assembler

Let's say we have this program:

```
    MOV  R5, #4
H2: MOV  R6, #10
H1: DJNZ R6, H1
    DJNZ R5, H2
```

1. After moving the data to the registers, microcontroller executes DJNZ R6, H1, which decrements R6 register **x**= 10 times.
2. In DJNZ R5, H2 we're charging 10 onto R6 again. Meaning that for every decrement on R5, we iterate 10 times, meaning that in total there are **y**= 40 iterations.

Why in every tutorial I've seen, the total number of iterations is of y=40 and not the actual total one x+y=50?

Comment: y= 40  already contains the x= 10 ... your `x+y=50` is same as `x + 4x = 50`

Answer (score 0):

Do you agree that regardless of what's inside it, the outer loop gets executed y = 4 times?

You've already stated that the inner loop executes x = 10 times.

So, for every iteration of the outer loop, you get 10 iterations of the inner loop. And therefore, the total number of iterations is y × x = 40.

In any case, x + y is not 50.

Comment: First, thanks for the reply. 
Secondly, why do we ignore what's inside the outer loop? That's what I don't get, because the main difference between this reasoning and mine is the fact that I consider what's happening inside outer loop!

Comment: Another thing I'm trying to understand is why, if this is a nested loop, do we start by executing the inner loop first? I mean, you start by reasoning what's happening in the outside loop first, so why shouldn't we make a SJMP to that instruction first?
I mean, doing an SJMP HERE between first and third instruction and tagging 
HERE: DJNZ R5, H2

Comment: @Agus It is not ignored. The outer loop executes 4 times, inner loop 10 times. What line or part of the code is unclear? If you understand for loops in C or Python or other language, do you understand nested for loops?